# Thread Issue : NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview, nullpointerexception

I have an issue when I am trying to set text from a last item of a listView into text View which is in the MainActivity.  It crashes during running time on “NullPointerException” because I think that that when I’m calling it in MainActivity, It didn’t finish to download on the ListView so when the MainActivity first launched, the listView did not finish his work and the functions getCount(),getItem() and my function getLastElement() are still null.
The issue is that I am not very good with dealing with Thread (Wait(), notify(),..)
Can you please help me with all this?

Here is my code and my LogCat :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private static Context mContext;

    public Button mExit, mHistory, mRating;

    public  TextView mSignal;

    HistoryAdapt myAdapter;

    HistoryItems m_myLastItem;

    ArrayList<HistoryItems> m_myListItem;

    Runnable m_run;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainActivity.mContext=getApplicationContext();

        mExit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ExitButton);
        mExit.setOnClickListener(this);

        mHistory=(Button)findViewById(R.id.HistoryButton);
        mHistory.setOnClickListener(this);

        mRating=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RateButton);
        mRating.setOnClickListener(this);

        mSignal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SignalOfTheDayTV);

        //### SET LAST ELEMENT INTO TEXTVIEW

        m_myListItem = new ArrayList<HistoryItems>(); 


        myAdapter= new HistoryAdapt(mContext, m_myListItem);

        new Thread(
                new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){

                            try{
                                ///Need to wait until the data to be downloaded inside HistoryAdapt so it can show the last element from the ListView here
                                HistoryParser parser = new HistoryParser();
                                parser.parse(getInputStream(HistoryAct.RSS_LINK));
                            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                                Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
                            } finally {
                                //notify that the data finished to download 
                                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(
                                    new Runnable(){
                                        public void run(){

                                                m_myLastItem = myAdapter.getLastElement();
                                                //set last signal into TextView
                                                mSignal.setText(m_myLastItem.getTitle());



                                        }
                                    }
                                );
                            }

                    }
                }
            ).run();



//#RATER
       //   AppRater.app_launched(this);

        //  AppRater.showRateDialog(this, null);


        //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
        ((AppManager) getApplication()).getTracker(AppManager.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    }//oncreate

    private InputStream getInputStream(String link) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(Constants.DATA, "Exception while retrieving the input stream", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static Context getAppContext(){
        return MainActivity.mContext;
    }


    public void ExitState(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("You're about to quit Signals4Trading");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.five);
        //builder.setMessage("Your device has been registered successfully. You'll receive signals very soon.");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);//can't click on the background of the activity
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"See you soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                finish();


            }//OnClickListener PositiveButton
        });//anonymous class PositiveButton
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enjoy your visit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog  = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }//ExitState

    public void goToHistoryActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryAct.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void rateApp(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Rate.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.ExitButton:
            ExitState();
            break;          

        case R.id.HistoryButton:
            goToHistoryActivity();
            break;

        case R.id.RateButton:
            rateApp();
            break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions etc.
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();

        //Stop the analytics tracking
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }

}//MainActivity


package com.Signals4Trading.push.android;

import java.util.List;





import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HistoryAdapt extends BaseAdapter {


    private final List<HistoryItems>items;
    private final Context context;

    public HistoryAdapt(Context context,List<HistoryItems>items){
        this.context=context;
        this.items=items;

    }//constructor

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id;
    }


 //###FUNCTION THAT RETURN LAST ELEMENT


     public HistoryItems getLastElement(){
        return items.get(items.size()-1); 
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.historyitems, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitleTV);
            holder.itemDate=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDateTV);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


         holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.itemDate.setText(items.get(position).getDate());

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView itemTitle;
        TextView itemDate;
    }


}
//HistoryAdapt

11-13 15:18:34.702: E/AndroidRuntime(7737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 15:18:34.702: E/AndroidRuntime(7737): Process: com.Signals4Trading.push.android, PID: 7737
11-13 15:18:34.702: E/AndroidRuntime(7737): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Signals4Trading.push.android/com.Signals4Trading.push.android.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
11-13 15:18:34.702: E/AndroidRuntime(7737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
```

Comment: what's at `HistoryAdapt.java:51`  ? Maybe `items` is not defined.

Comment: Not quite sure, but maybe a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) is what you need?

Comment: I edit my code and verify that the item is not null before returning it. It still crashed on the same issue :nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to perform an asynchronous operation using a runnable, then before the asynchronous operation is completed you're trying to use the value it is supposed to set. So I'm assuming you're trying to create a background thread that waits for the data and updates/notifies the UI/UI-thread when it's done loading. This would mean that the asynchronous operation is created and started by the UI-thread during OnCreate and while it is running the UI-thread can happily go on executing the OnCreate method and loading the UI etc.

First of all, it looks like you're creating a runnable but not running it. If you want to run the runnable in a different (asynchronous) thread, try this:

```
new Thread(
    new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void Run()
        {
            //your code here
        }
    }
).Run();
```

*note: Translated this from C#, may not be 100% correct (caps?) but should be really easy to get working.

It's not entirely clear from your code but I assume the code in your runnable fills the HistoryAdapt class with data. Be careful not to create concurrency issues this way. If two threads are trying to access the same object at the same time you may have problems so be sure to properly "lock" objects before using them in seperate threads. In java you can use  a "synch" clause to do this:

```
synchronized(this){
    this = newvalue;   
}
```

This makes sure that while the code inside the braces is executing the "this" object cannot be accessed by other threads. Other threads will then wait untill the code is executed and the object is released before continuing.

Secondly, you should be aware that the runnable/thread you've created is basicly a thread that is run once and then disposed (so not a dedicated thread). In this case monitor/wait is not really necessary. You could simply include the code that updates the UI (mSignal.setText(m_myLastItem.getTitle());) in the finally clause of your try/catch statement. Be sure to use the runOnUiThread method when you're trying to update/edit UI-elements from seperate threads like so:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        m_myLastItem = HistoryAdapt.getLastElement();
        //set last signal into TextView
        mSignal.setText(m_myLastItem.getTitle());
    }
});
```

This way, the thread is created in OnCreate, does its job seperately from the UI-thread, then updates the UI as soon as it is done. One possible problem you might have is that mSignal.setText() could get called at a moment when the UI isnt ready to be updated, not sure this will really be a problem in this case though. Also, when using this technique in other places you may need a reference to your activity to use inside your thread (you can't always get a reference from the place where you're defining the thread/runnable), that's easy enough, just make a static reference to your activity somewhere in your app and reference that (i prefer an App_Session class for static variables used app-wide).

Hope I understood the  question correctly and this helps. In any case, good luck!

*Edit: Full example

```
new Thread(
    new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(!HistoryAdapt.hasBeenInitiated)
            {
                try
                {
                    ///Need to wait until the data to be downloaded inside HistoryAdapt so it can show the last element from the ListView here
                    HistoryParser parser = new HistoryParser();
                    parser.parse(getInputStream(HistoryAct.RSS_LINK));
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
                } finally {
                    //notify that the data finished to download 
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(
                        new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                if (!HistoryAdapt.hasBeenInitiated)
                                {
                                    m_myLastItem = HistoryAdapt.getLastElement();
                                    //set last signal into TextView
                                    mSignal.setText(m_myLastItem.getTitle());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
).run();
```

- Could not test this unfortunately since i can't run Java (i use xamarin), should be correct though, maybe the  @override isnt needed and im not sure if it's supposed to be 'Run' or  'run'. I'm sure you'll figure that out though ;)

Comment: What about using Observer Object?

Comment: I've never needed to use an Observer but from what I've read it seems unneccesarily complex for this case. You could use an Observer but you'd have to create a class that implements IObserveable, create an instance of it, register listeners and (when the event has been triggered and is no longer needed) unregister listeners and dispose of the object. The above solution seems much simpler plus if you get the hang of it you'll be well on your way to understanding the basics of multi-threaded programming (which is very useful :)).

Comment: I still think, he would be better off using a Loader.

Comment: Loader does look interesting though it is only available since Android 3.0. I've never used it but would be interested to see it in action. Maye you could provide an example or link to an example?

Regardless of which solution would be less work the above method does work for many different things though (all kinds of asynch operations) and is really handy to know either way :).

Comment: Please have a look on my edited code. I've tried to reproduce what you learned to me. Unfortunately, it still crashes during runtime

Comment: Edited my answer with a full example. Also note that im not using the variable "m_run" anymore since you don't really seem to use it anywhere else in your code.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for your answer! Actually, your code was perfect. It did not show any warning! When I tried to run it again, it still crash on same issue. Please look at my edited code and LogCat. What should I provide you in order to resolve my issue?

Comment: Looks like getLastElement is a static method of the HistoryAdapt class. The getLastElement method uses the static field "items" which is a List. The only place I see 'items' getting set to a value is in the constructor of HistoryAdapt. I do not see that constructor being called anywhere in your code though. I assumed you're calling the constructor somewhere in here:

    ///Need to wait until the data to be downloaded inside HistoryAdapt so it can show the last element from the ListView here
    HistoryParser parser = new HistoryParser();
    parser.parse(getInputStream(HistoryAct.RSS_LINK));

Comment: Needless to say you need to call that constructor to set 'items' to a value before trying to access 'items' or it will be null. And you're welcome :)

Comment: Ok, got it. I replace all the static functions with regular ones, initiate Adapter and ArrayList<HistoryItems>(). Now it crashes on java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1. Please have a look on my edited code + logcat

Comment: Well that one is easy to  find: return items.get(items.size()-1); apparently items.size() is 0! So even though the items object is now being created/initialized properly (and is no longer null), it is still not being filled with data. You'll have to make sure that after you've loaded your data you put it in the 'items' object. Also its always a good idea to check if "items.size() > 0" before trying something like 'items.get(items.size() -1)'.

Comment: I don't really think you need my help on these kind of problems though, with some proper debugging tools you should be able to find these problems easily. What program are you using to code/build/debug, Eclipse? And are you familiar with breakpoints? If not then check them out, they make debugging so much easier! Using logcat only is a pretty dang hard way to debug, check out this video on Eclipse breakpoints: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drk_ldaRMaY

And thanks for accepting the answer by the way, woohoo, my first reputation points :)

Comment: *One note on that video: Instead of "Debug as Java program", use "Debug as Android Application"

Comment: Ok, I wrote this :  public HistoryItems getLastElement(){
   
   HistoryItems lastItem= items.get(items.size());
   if(items!=null && !items.isEmpty()){  
    
    lastItem = items.get(items.size()-1);
   }
   
    return lastItem;       
   
 }
 and it sill crashes on ArrayOutOFBound(): Invalid Index : 0, size is 0. What do I wrong?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, i will have a look. Many thanks for your precious help:)

Comment: The first item in an array (or list) is always located at array[0], so if you have an array with a length of 0 then array[0] does not exist! So always be careful that you check the length of an array or list before trying to access it using array[index] or you might get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Also it looks like you'll have to find out why your array isnt being filled with the data you're trying to load. In any case, good luck and glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `onCreate()` call in the `Activity` is calling:

```
m_myLastItem= HistoryAdapt.getLastElement();
```

But, the constructor for `HistoryAdapt` has not been called yet, and that is where you initialize the static field `items` within it.  I would recommend rethinking this class and its usage as you're using it in an instance manner but have it partially coded as if it is a static class.  A good rule of thumb to follow is don't make your static methods dependent on the class being constructed.  At that point it's just an instance method.

Comment: Ok, Please look at my edited code, inside mainActivity. I triggered with "!HasBeenInitiate". Is still crash on runningtime for the same issue as before

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread run = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

    run =  new Thread( new Runnable(){
                public void run(){

            if(!HistoryAdapt.hasBeenInitiated){

                try {
                    ///Need to wait until the data to be downloaded inside HistoryAdapt so it can show the last element from the ListView here

                        HistoryParser parser = new HistoryParser();
                        parser.parse(getInputStream(HistoryAct.RSS_LINK));
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
                }finally{

                    //notify that the data finished to download 
                }

            }
                }
            });

        run.start();
        run.join();
```

use this but it will wait until your run thread finish.

Comment: OP is aware of that. He is asking _how_ to do exactly that.

Comment: That's making no sense at all. Starting a thread and then waiting for it. You could as well drop the thread. Probable source for unresponsive Activity ...

Comment: What do you think about using Observer Object?

Comment: Yup its best solution but it take architecture changes in your code if it a big one,I will provide you answer wait some time till then you can use above code.Thanks